# make div ::after element outside it

Tags: css

i want to make my :after element outside my div after the red border, but is shows inside it. how to make the green border outside the red border right after it?

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, eum.</p>
</div>

div {
    padding: 5em;
    border: solid 1px red;
    &::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 3px solid green;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not standard CSS. You'll have to tag what that is.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the pseudo-element a `position: absolute` to let it break out of its parent container, the `div`.  Then position it below div with `left` and `bottom`, setting the bottom to however far down you want it in negative numbers.  Make sure to give the div a `position: relative` so that the `after` element will stay relative to it.

```css
div {
    padding: 5em;
    border: solid 1px red;
    position: relative;
}

div::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -1rem;
        left: 0;
        border-bottom: 3px solid green;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, eum.</p>
</div>
```